# Periodic Email Notifications (Windows Azure .Net)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, email

I have an application written in C# ASP.Net MVC4 and running on Windows Azure Website. I would like to write a service / job to perform following: 
1. Read the user information from the website database 
2. Build a user-wise site activity summary 
3. Generate an HTML email message that includes the summary for each user account 
4. Periodically send such emails to each user

I am new to Windows Azure Cloud Services and would like to know best approach / solution to achieve the above.

Based on my study so far, I see that independent Worker Role of Cloud Services along with [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) and [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) would be a best fit. Please suggest.

Comment: We did exactly that, except using a homegrown email writer rather than Postal. It works well. You're on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but... Remember that a Worker Role (or Web Role) is basically a blueprint for a Windows Server VM, and you run one or more instances of that role definition. And that VM, just like Windows Server running locally, can perform a bunch of tasks simultaneously. So... there's no need to create a separate worker role just for doing hourly emails. Think about it: For nearly an hour, it'll be sitting idle, and you'll be paying for it (for however many instances of the role you launch, and you cannot drop it to zero - you'll always need minimum one instance).

If, however, you create a thread on an existing worker or web role, which simply sleeps for an hour and then does the email updates, you basically get this ability at no extra cost (and you should hopefully cause minimal impact to the other tasks running on that web/worker role's instances).

One thing you'll need to do, independent of separate role or reused role: Be prepared for multiple instances. That is: If you have two role instances, they'll both be running the code to check every hour. So you'll need a scheme to prevent both instances doing the same task. This can be solved in several ways. For example: Use a queue message that stays invisible for an hour, then appears, and your code would check maybe every minute for a queue message (and the first one who gets it does the hourly stuff). Or maybe run quartz.net.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't know postal, but it seems like the right combination to use.